# "If Spinner = Value Then" in Android Studio

Tags: android

It's Will Be Good For Your Help,,

i have 2 Spinner + Mediam Text + Button

- First Spinner "hint" [where i'm Now] 
  (Los angeles, California, London)
- Second Spinner "hint" [i Want To Go]
   (Florida, Origin, London)
- When i Click On Button, Will Show Result in Text Box ..

Example:

When I choose I'm in "Los angeles" And Want To Go "London" Then Result Will Show in Text Box, that Says "If you Want Go To London You Have To Travel with Airplane".

Please explain because I'm Lv1 in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..!

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner temp1,temp2;
TextView t1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);

    temp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.temp);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>   adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.temperature,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
temp1.setAdapter(adapter);

   temp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.temp2);
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.temperature,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
temp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
temp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
temp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Spinner temp1=(Spinner)parent;
    Spinner temp2=(Spinner)parent;
    if (temp1.getId()==R.id.temp) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        t1.setText(item);
    }
    if (temp2.getId()==R.id.temp2) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        t1.setText(item);
    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: I will Try It ,, Thx For your Effort :)

Comment: Atman Bhatt 

But there The TextView "Message' When i Selected From 2 Spinner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120063/if-spinner-value-then-in-android-studio @CharuPriya – AkashG